# TypeError: unhashable type 'list' when trying to download image by link

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, python-2.x

Trying to save file by link, but face `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

```
import requests
import lxml
page = requests.get('https://karabas.com')
for link in links:
   event_page = requests.get(link)
   tree_event_page = html.fromstring(event_page.content)
   image = tree_event_page.xpath('//figure[@class="photo"]/meta/@content')
   f = open('00000001.jpg','w+')
   f.write(requests.get(image).content)
```

`image` variable is a link. What's wrong with the way I am trying to download image?

Example of link: https://image.karabas.com/w/350/h/496/f/files/import/1308758146_ImageBig636415263072975494.jpg

Comment: Why not post your actual traceback?  They're **helpful**.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your error, possibly because you have left out essential parts of your code, e.g., `page` is never used and `links` is never defined.  In any case, I believe that your bug may be due to the fact that your `image` variable is a list of strings (corresponding to links), not a single link as you believe.  This is what the [`xpath` method](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method) returns.

So, if you know that there's exactly one result to be returned, you need something like:

```
image = tree_event_page.xpath('//figure[@class="photo"]/meta/@content')[0]
```

The emphasis is on the `[0]` at the end.

---

PS: After a bit of guessing, I confirm that the script below works as you probably intended:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

links = ['https://kiev.karabas.com/pro-mishej-ta-lyudej-2']
for link in links:
   event_page = requests.get(link)
   tree_event_page = html.fromstring(event_page.content)
   image = tree_event_page.xpath('//figure[@class="photo"]/meta/@content')[0]
   with open('00000001.jpg','w+') as f:
      f.write(requests.get(image).content)
```